# Good Model Calibration Books/Papers for Common Option Pricing Models

Tags: option-pricing, models, calibration, books

I am trying to find a good book which focuses on the model calibration. I just want to know generally, what are the most common methods of model calibration(such as Black-Scholes Model, Stochastic Volatility Model(Heston), Jump-Diffusion Model, Hull-White Model and so on, all the models which are at a master level of Mathematical finance program)? But it seems all mathematical finance books didn't discuss a lot about the model calibration, is there a good book/paper on model calibration?

Comment: Can you please specify which models you attempt to calibrate? There are at least 100 calibration techniques out there, each pertaining to a different model.

Comment: such as Black-Scholes Model, Stochastic Volatility Model(Heston), Jump-Diffusion Model, Hull-White Model and so on, all the models which are at a master level of Mathematical finance program.  I want to know what are the most common methods of model calibration for these models?

Comment: They are each calibrated differently. You need to be more specific if you look for help.

Answer (score 3):

[Jim Gatherals Book](http://www.amazon.de/The-Volatility-Surface-Practitioners-Finance/dp/0471792519/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1362223742&sr=8-1) deals with the models you mention and gives an intuitive understanding about calibration and issues that arise. Mostly basic stuff, but very useful if you're just starting out. Also very understandable without an extensive math background.